# No data to read after the socket has been duplicated

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, client-server, ipc

I am writing a portable application (windows -linux) client-server using the C language.
This application must be able to work using either a fixed set of threads or a fixed set of processes to handle client requests.
I'm using curl as a client.
I've easily solved the thread question with pthread. As far as the processes are concerned, the question is a little more complex.
When the main server receives the client's request, it receives an authentication header with the user ID and password encoded in base64.
Using threads, each thread can read this header, using processes instead this does not happen. The process that is created by the main server to handle the request blocks on the recv, even if on the socket before the duplication there was this authentication header ready to be read. Is this due to something happening during the duplication?
**Initially to understand how everything works I wrote about the code in which**:
1 The main server accepts a client request

```
if ((clientSocket = accept(MySocket, (struct sockaddr *)&cad,&clientLen)) < 0) {
        ErrorHandler("accept() failed.\n");
        // CHIUSURA DELLA CONNESSIONE
        closesocket(MySocket);
        ClearWinSock();

        return 0;
    }
```

2 The main server creates a named pipe

```
hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe"),
                        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,   // FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE is not needed but forces CreateNamedPipe(..) to fail if the pipe already exists...
                        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
                        512,
                        512,
                        NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
                        NULL);
```

3 The main server creates a process that must handle the request

```
    STARTUPINFO info;
    GetStartupInfo(&info);
    WSAPROTOCOL_INFO protInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    if(CreateProcess("connectionHandler.exe",NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
    { 
        printf("ok");
    }  
    else
    {
        printf("server:The process could not be started...\n");
    }
```

4 The main server duplicates the socket client and waits for the newly created process to connect to the pipe to receive the duplicate socket and uses the named pipe to pass the duplicate client sockets to the created process

```
 if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE)   // wait for someone to connect to the pipe
    {
        printf("process connected\n");
        if ( WriteFile(hPipe, &clientSocket, sizeof(clientSocket), &dwBytes, NULL) == 0 ) {
        return -1;
        }
        if ( WriteFile(hPipe, &protInfo, sizeof(protInfo), &dwBytes, NULL) == 0 ) {
        return -1;
        }
        while (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &dwRead, NULL) != FALSE)
        {
            buffer[dwRead] = '\0';
            printf("from client: %s", buffer);
        }
    }
    printf("data passed to process\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
```

5 The created process uses this socket to read the data.

```
hPipe = CreateFile(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe"), 
                   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                   0,
                   NULL,
                   OPEN_EXISTING,
                   0,
                   NULL);
if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    WriteFile(hPipe,
              "Hello Pipe\n",
              12,   // = length of string + terminating '\0' !!!
              &dwWritten,
              NULL);
    dwMode = PIPE_READMODE_BYTE;
    SetNamedPipeHandleState(
    hPipe,
    &dwMode,  // new mode
    NULL,
    NULL);

    ReadFile(hPipe, &sock_client, sizeof(sock_client), &dwBytes, NULL);
    printf("client: sock client = %i\n",sock_client);
    fflush(stdout);

/* I read the protocol information structure sent me by the parent process */

    ReadFile(hPipe, &protInfo, sizeof(protInfo), &dwBytes, NULL);
    printf("protocol read\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    sock_client = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, &protInfo, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
    printf("calling connection_handler...\n");  //function that cal recv and read the header
    fflush(stdout);
    connection_handler((void*)sock_client);
```

7: connection_handler((void*)sock_client):
This function gets the pointer to the duplicated socket and calls the recv to receive the header, then works on the header by extrapolating the base64 string and decoding it.
It works perfectly with threads, but blocks on the recv as if the header that was sent by the client, when the connection with the main server was accepted, was lost after the duplication and the passage of the socket.
Function code:

```
printf("start connection handler\n");
fflush(stdout);
//Get the socket descriptor
int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;

char server_reply[2000];

int recv_size;
printf("preparing to receive client data\n");
fflush(stdout);
if((recv_size = recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0)) == SOCK_ERR)
{
    printf("recv failed");
    fflush(stdout);
}
else
{
    printf("Reply received\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
...
```

Is there anything theoretical that escapes me? 
ps: Please do not comment on the style of the code, it is just a test to understand how the communication between processes and the passage of a socket works.

Comment: create new process for every connections bad idea. sockets which you create is inheritable. as result you not need it duplicate second time. it already duplicated, because you create process with `bInheritHandles == true`. you can pass socket value (it will be the same as in parent process) via command line. not need use pipe at all

Comment: I know I just wanted to understand well the passage of sockets and the communication between processes. I will not use a process for each request but a fixed number of reusable processes.
your answer was very helpful. Thanks

Comment: windows associate with socket handle in user mode additional context. in process where socket created. if you duplicate socket to another process - this context will be not duplicated and i not sure are this duplicated socket will be full function. never test this

Comment: I have "thin" the program, now when I create the process I pass it as a parameter the value of the socket (in char *), the process converts the value into integer and executes the recv on that value. recv fails.
If I do the recv inside the server, the authentication header is received correctly.

Comment: i guess this exactly because duplicated socket handle (without user mode context) not functional. the `WriteFile` and `ReadFile` wok with this socket however. try for test only use `ReadFile` in place `recv` - which will be result or error code ?

Comment: read function used within the process returns -1.
It looks as if the socket value is invalid. But it is the same integer stored by the server.

Comment: use `ReadFile`, not `read`. and `ReadFile` never return -1. it return 0 (false) on fail and `GetLastError`. `recv` also return `WsaGetLastError` which you must show

Comment: I used ReadFile but it blocks forever.
I can not figure out what the problem is at this point.

Comment: blocks for ever say how minimum about you use valid file handle. `recv` fail - which error return `WSAGetLastError` ? always post error code. not just say call fail

Comment: recapitulating: the process correctly receives the entire socket descriptor.
Now I tried to use ReadFile but I get the code 87 as an error: One or more parameters are invalid.
this is a piece of the code:
int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;  
 
 TCHAR server_reply[2000];  
 
 printf("preparing to receive client data\n");  
 fflush(stdout);  
 
 DWORD nRead;  
 BOOL rf;  
 HANDLE socket = (HANDLE)sock;  
 if(!(rf=ReadFile(socket, server_reply, 40, &nRead,   NULL)))
 {
  printf("error: %i",WSAGetLastError());
  fflush(stdout);
 }

Comment: i check - `recv` must work if you pass valid socket handle.

Comment: I pass to the recv the same value that I have in the server and that I have passed to the process. For example if in the server the socket value is 240, unsing printf  I can see how the value is the same even after the passage.So the recv receives the exact same socket value.

Comment: @RbMm After a bit of debugging I solved.
The primary error that led to other errors was related to the recv.
recv gave as error 10093. In practice, I had not initialized winsock in the process (I did it only on the server). Initializing winsock with WSAStartup now all works correctly.